# How to store dictionary values into an array from array of dictionaries in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, dictionary, swift, tableview

i'm new to iOS development i'm trying to display data in tableview in swift the data is coming from webservice for that i used NSURLSessionDataTask. The data was coming as shown below:

```
{ categorys: [
              {
                category_id: "all",
                category_name: "ALL",
                category_desc: "All Categories"
              },
              {
                category_id: "1",
                category_name: "Art",
                category_desc: "Artffsdfsdfds "
              },
              {
                category_id: "4",
                category_name: "Education",
                category_desc: "Education for children and adults"
              }]
   }
```

I want to display "category_name" names in tableview.
Below is the code what i've tried and trying to display the names in tableview.

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate
{

@IBOutlet var dataTableView: UITableView!

var items: NSArray = []

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //table
    self.dataTableView!.delegate = self
    self.dataTableView!.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    self.view.addSubview(self.dataTableView)

    getData({data, error -> Void in
        if (data != nil)
        {
            self.items = NSMutableArray(array: data)
            self.dataTableView!.reloadData()
        }
        else
        {
            println("api.getData failed")
            println(error)
        }
    })

}

func getData(completionHandler: ((NSArray!, NSError!) -> Void)!) -> Void
{
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://sample.com/srd/games/category")!
    var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL:url)
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        if (error != nil)
        {
            return completionHandler(nil, error)
        }

        var error: NSError?
        let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary


        let names = json["categorys"] as NSArray
        println(names)

    })
    task.resume()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
{
    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    cell.textLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.row]["categorys"] as? NSString


    return cell
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this can help you. swift codes

```
    var dic_categorys : NSDictionary! // original Dictionary
    //
    var array_item : NSArray! = dic_categorys.valueForKey("categorys") as NSArray
    if let array = array_item {

        var array_list : NSMutableArray! =  NSMutableArray(array:array)
        var array_list_category_name : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
        //
        for item in array_list {
            var dic_item : NSDictionary! = item as NSDictionary
            if let dic = dic_item {
                array_list_category_name.addObject(dic.valueForKey("category_name")!)
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer JNY, in the above i'm able to get array of dictionaries that means "categorys" array. I'm unable retrieve "category_name". Unfortunately your code also not worked for me. When i put your code and runs it crashes.

Comment: print your dic_categorys！and which line code crashed?

Comment: At this line i'm getting crash "var array_item : NSArray! = dic_categorys.valueForKey("categorys") as NSArray". The error is fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
Printing description of array_item:
<OS_dispatch_data: data[0x7ffd2b704e30] = { composite, size = 1872, num_records = 2 record[0] = { from = 0, length = 384, data_object = 0x7ffd2b730a30 }, record[1] = { from = 0, length = 1488, data_object = 0x7ffd2b704df0 }, }>

Printing description of array:
(NSArray) array = 0x000000010f489c13 {
  ObjectiveC.NSObject = {}
}

Comment: @SVS please, you need set value for "dic_categorys"!!!  im just define it.